# Spamassassin is filtering trusted account

Tags: spamassassin

To deal with bad guys trying to send mails with forged **From** field including **@mydomain.tld**, I used to have thoses rules in `spamassassin/local.cf`:

```
trusted_networks   my.ip.add.ress
score    ALL_TRUSTED           -100
header   FAKE_LOCAL_SENDERS    From =~ /\@mydomain.tld/
score    FAKE_LOCAL_SENDERS    10
```

Recently I moved the mail server to a new device, featuring Centos 8.
Since then legitimate e-mails sent from `127.0.0.1` (without SMTP auth) are filtered.
After investigating, I figured that FAKE_LOCAL_SENDERS score is still applied when ALL_TRUSTED score is not.

Worth to mention:

- According to logs and headers, the detected client is indeed `127.0.0.1`
- I've looked for other `.cf` files in `/etc` but didn't find anything relevant
- I've also looked for ALL_TRUSTED string but didn't find other occurence

Looking into [the documentation](https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.4.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Conf.html), I couldn't even find anything about this ALL_TRUSTED symbolic name.

I found it's *for trusted host only via SMTP*, in [Tests Performed v3.3.x](https://spamassassin.apache.org/old/tests_3_3_x.html).
But I couldn't find the same document for my spamassassin version (v3.4.2).

Maybe there's another way to filter forged **From**, I don't know.
I'll appreciate if anyone knows how to have this work.

---

EDIT: since I've been asked, here are more detailed infos.

**postfix logs**:

```
Jul  9 14:58:46 mail postfix/pickup[21731]: 981041958: uid=0 from=<root>
Jul  9 14:58:46 mail postfix/cleanup[21766]: 981041958: message-id=<20200709075846.981041958@mail.mydomain.tld>
Jul  9 14:58:46 mail opendkim[21646]: 981041958: DKIM-Signature field added (s=mydomain.tld, d=mydomain.tld)
Jul  9 14:58:46 mail postfix/qmgr[21732]: 981041958: from=<root@mydomain.tld>, size=313, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  9 14:58:47 mail postfix/10025/smtpd[21774]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jul  9 14:58:47 mail postfix/10025/smtpd[21774]: 2997053: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jul  9 14:58:47 mail postfix/cleanup[21766]: 2997053: message-id=<20200709075846.981041958@mail.mydomain.tld>
Jul  9 14:58:47 mail opendkim[21646]: 2997053: DKIM-Signature field added (s=mydomain.tld, d=mydomain.tld)
Jul  9 14:58:47 mail postfix/qmgr[21732]: 2997053: from=<root@mydomain.tld>, size=1514, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  9 14:58:47 mail amavis[21734]: (21734-01) Passed SPAM {RelayedTaggedInbound,Quarantined}, [127.0.0.1] <root@mydomain.tld> -> <root@mydomain.tld>, Message-ID: <20200709075846.981041958@mail.mydomain.tld>, mail_id: fr9Pzi3DYtmO, Hits: 10.9, size: 705, queued_as: 2997053, 556 ms
Jul  9 14:58:47 mail postfix/amavis/smtp[21771]: 981041958: to=<root@mydomain.tld>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=0.86, delays=0.17/0.13/0/0.55, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 2997053)
Jul  9 14:58:47 mail postfix/qmgr[21732]: 981041958: removed
Jul  9 14:58:47 mail dovecot[21781]: lda(me@mydomain.tld): sieve: msgid=<20200709075846.981041958@mail.mydomain.tld>: stored mail into mailbox 'Junk'
Jul  9 14:58:47 mail postfix/pipe[21780]: 2997053: to=<me@mydomain.tld>, orig_to=<root@mydomain.tld>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.38, delays=0.21/0.01/0/0.16, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
Jul  9 14:58:47 mail postfix/qmgr[21732]: 2997053: removed
```

**received mail headers**:

```
Return-Path: <root@mydomain.tld>
X-Original-To: root@mydomain.tld
Delivered-To: me@mydomain.tld
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.mydomain.tld (Postfix) with ESMTP id 2997053
    for <root@mydomain.tld>; Thu,  9 Jul 2020 14:58:47 +0700 (+07)
DKIM-Filter: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 mail.mydomain.tld 2997053
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mydomain.tld;
    s=mydomain.tld; t=1594281527;
    bh=Pb3GbVbRabH8he07wAoFCdFxIXnMcJZfD3IMOd8OwIU=;
    h=Subject:Date:From:From;
    b=4aenJY5Qg8lKtX7amYiCHKuile4cEaO5gRk+HzdInYH5BIl96FY+SwVwyYdCFUUSJ
     MR/UsQM47wmxJSafYFF7xE1BNxXqe/DtejiQjuumvZG9OhgJRo79kPJ3Or/J7yvETs
     OLq6Bk3nbj3JsK3dcUxPBcC2E6WPfyFbw+2o6zQk=
X-Virus-Scanned: amavisd-new at mydomain.tld
X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-Spam-Score: 10.9
X-Spam-Level: **********
X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=10.9 tagged_above=2 required=6.2
    tests=[BAYES_00=-1.9, DKIM_SIGNED=0.1, DKIM_VALID=-0.1,
    DKIM_VALID_AU=-0.1, DKIM_VALID_EF=-0.1, FAKE_LOCAL_SENDERS=10,
    MISSING_HEADERS=3, NO_RELAYS=-0.001, URIBL_BLOCKED=0.001]
    autolearn=no autolearn_force=no
Received: from mail.mydomain.tld ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (mail.mydomain.tld [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id fr9Pzi3DYtmO for <root@mydomain.tld>;
    Thu,  9 Jul 2020 14:58:46 +0700 (+07)
Received: by mail.mydomain.tld (Postfix, from userid 0)
    id 981041958; Thu,  9 Jul 2020 14:58:46 +0700 (+07)
DKIM-Filter: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 mail.mydomain.tld 981041958
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mydomain.tld;
    s=mydomain.tld; t=1594281526;
    bh=Pb3GbVbRabH8he07wAoFCdFxIXnMcJZfD3IMOd8OwIU=;
    h=Subject:Date:From:From;
    b=vnht27+6RxYrr/uoq2kJUzWPNIwzHoE6yqVWuQ4eyXGcoBqhQlb7I8fLNuW+OlT3C
     P0rPqWxVGGxigDyPMH9m/t0VLoF9drO9RA3NYc2FgF6S8J4XBcA3+z3GogzAJ82vto
     pFMXVGyqHlFsEPDkhuQz8V2P/AHduKzkg//L13HY=
Subject: ***Spam*** Test mail
Message-Id: <20200709075846.981041958@mail.mydomain.tld>
Date: Thu,  9 Jul 2020 14:58:46 +0700 (+07)
From: root <root@mydomain.tld>
```

**spamassassin/local.cf**:

```
# These values can be overridden by editing ~/.spamassassin/user_prefs.cf 
# (see spamassassin(1) for details)

# These should be safe assumptions and allow for simple visual sifting
# without risking lost emails.

required_hits 5
report_safe 0
rewrite_header Subject [SPAM]

## MY CONF
use_bayes 1
bayes_path /var/spool/amavisd/.spamassassin/bayes

header   __RCVD_IN_HOSTKARMA eval:check_rbl('HOSTKARMA-lastexternal','hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com.')
describe __RCVD_IN_HOSTKARMA Sender listed in JunkEmailFilter
tflags   __RCVD_IN_HOSTKARMA net

header   RCVD_IN_HOSTKARMA_W eval:check_rbl_sub('HOSTKARMA-lastexternal', '127.0.0.1')
describe RCVD_IN_HOSTKARMA_W Sender listed in HOSTKARMA-WHITE
tflags   RCVD_IN_HOSTKARMA_W net nice
score    RCVD_IN_HOSTKARMA_W -5

header   RCVD_IN_HOSTKARMA_BL eval:check_rbl_sub('HOSTKARMA-lastexternal', '127.0.0.2')
describe RCVD_IN_HOSTKARMA_BL Sender listed in HOSTKARMA-BLACK
tflags   RCVD_IN_HOSTKARMA_BL net
score    RCVD_IN_HOSTKARMA_BL 3.0

header   RCVD_IN_HOSTKARMA_BR eval:check_rbl_sub('HOSTKARMA-lastexternal', '127.0.0.4')
describe RCVD_IN_HOSTKARMA_BR Sender listed in HOSTKARMA-BROWN
tflags   RCVD_IN_HOSTKARMA_BR net
score    RCVD_IN_HOSTKARMA_BR 1.0

header   RCVD_IN_BL_SPAMCOP_NET   eval:check_rbl_txt('spamcop', 'bl.spamcop.net.', '(?i:spamcop)')
describe RCVD_IN_BL_SPAMCOP_NET Received via a relay in bl.spamcop.net
tflags   RCVD_IN_BL_SPAMCOP_NET   net
#reuse    RCVD_IN_BL_SPAMCOP_NET
score    RCVD_IN_HOSTKARMA_BR 3.0

## testing
score    MISSING_FROM   5.0
score    MISSING_DATE   5.0
score    MISSING_HEADERS 3.0
score    PDS_FROM_2_EMAILS 3.0
score    EMPTY_MESSAGE 5.0
score    FREEMAIL_DISPTO 2.0
score    FREEMAIL_FORGED_REPLYTO 3.5
score    DKIM_ADSP_NXDOMAIN 5.0
score    FORGED_GMAIL_RCVD 2.5

# from mydomain.tld
header   FAKE_LOCAL_SENDERS  From =~ /\@mydomain.tld/
score    FAKE_LOCAL_SENDERS  10
trusted_networks my.ip.add.ress
score    ALL_TRUSTED     -100
```

Note: I only edited the domain name and the IP address.

You may notice than while there is a command:

```
rewrite_header Subject [SPAM]
```

The final subject in headers is prefixed with `***Spam***`, this is overridden by dovecot.

```
$sa_spam_subject_tag = '***Spam*** ';
```

Comment: Please show the actual logs, headers, and configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I just did

Comment: Hmm. The SA config seems OK at first glance. But, if the source IP address is really trusted, do you need to send it to SpamAssassin at all? You could just have Postfix skip it.

Comment: Sure, I might do that, thanks. It's just I'd like to understand what's going on here...
This very same config was working great on Gentoo.